# Finding the Path of a Piecewise Smooth Parametrized Curve

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, parametrization, line-integrals

Suppose $\phi: [0,5] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is the piecewise smooth parametrized curve given by
\begin{align*}
\phi(t) &= 
\begin{cases}
\left(-1 + \cos\left(\frac{5\pi}{4} + \frac{\pi t}{2}\right), 1 + \sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{4} + \frac{\pi t}{2}\right)\right) & \text{if $0\leq t < 1$} \\
\left((\sqrt{2}-1) + \cos\left(\frac{5\pi}{4} - \frac{\pi t}{2}\right), (\sqrt{2}-1)\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{4} - \frac{\pi t}{2}\right)\right) & \text{if $1\leq t < 4$} \\
\left(-1 + \cos\left(\frac{-7\pi}{4} + \frac{\pi t}{2}\right), -1 + \sin\left(\frac{-7\pi}{4} + \frac{\pi t}{2}\right)\right) & \text{if $4\leq t \leq 5$}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

What would the sketch of the path $C_{\phi}$ look like in $\mathbb{R}^2$? I tried to plug in the numbers corresponding to $t$, but I can't seem to figure out what the shape of the curve looks like geometrically. Furthermore, can we find another parametrization of this curve that is not equivalent to $\phi$ or $-\phi$?

I would very much appreciate any help with this question. Thanks!

Comment: @Gribouillis You are right...

Comment: It looks like circular arcs or elliptical arcs (for the second one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first and third part are circular arcs. The second part is an elliptical arc.
[image: Parametrized curve]

Python code

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

t = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
x = -1 + np.cos((5/4 + t/2)*np.pi)
y = 1 + np.sin((5/4 + t/2)*np.pi)
ax.plot(x, y)

t = np.linspace(1, 4, 100)
x = np.sqrt(2)-1 + np.cos((5/4 - t/2)*np.pi)
y = (np.sqrt(2)-1) *  np.sin((5/4 - t/2)*np.pi)
ax.plot(x, y)

t = np.linspace(4, 5, 100)
x = -1 + np.cos((-7/4 + t/2)*np.pi)
y = -1 + np.sin((-7/4 + t/2)*np.pi)
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.axis('equal')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The curves are a quarter circle, a 270 degree ellipse, and another quarter circle, respectively. Any curve plotting software would tell you this, if you couldn’t see it from the equations. Mathematica, for example, or [this package](https://www.geogebra.org/m/cAsHbXEU).

For alternative parameterizations, there are a few things you could do.

1. Shift the domains
2. Scale the domains
3. Replace the trig functions by rational functions using the [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution).